# open link in current tab while tab is pinned

Tags: macos, safari, mojave

1. Google anything
2. Pin that Tab
3. Click the first result

It opens in a new tab.

How can I force it to open in the current tab?

Comment: If it opened in the current tab then it wouldn't be 'pinned', would it?  Pinning keeps the tab open on that site.  By default, pinned tabs stay on the current location and open links in new tabs.